# Delete object in array when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a small project with some fields that can insert and delete array objects. I have a problem on removing the selected row (using a checkbox) from my Array Object. Remove function works but does not remove the object in my array.

below is my html.

```
<div class="container">
    <input id="list-input" />
    <select id="select-status">
        <option value="on-going">on-going</option>
        <option value="completed">completed</option>
    </select>
    <button id="add">Add To List</button>
    <button id="delete">Remove From List</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Your List</h1>

    <div id="mylist">
        <table id="mylist">
            <thead>
                <th>ID Number</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button id="clear">clear</button>
</div>
```

and my js for my add and remove function

```
var tasks = [];
var count = 0;

$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function() {
    var desc    = $.trim($('#list-input').val());
    var status  = $('#select-status').val();
    var id      = Date.now();
    item        = {};

    if (!desc) {
        item.id = "";
        alert("Input a description");
        return;
    }

    //clear input field
    $('#list-input').val('');
    $('#list-input').focus();

    item.id          = id;
    item.description = desc;
    item.status      = status;
    tasks.push(item);


    var row  = "<tr>";
        row += "<td id="+ item.id +">" + item.id + "</td>";
        row += "<td>" + item.description + "</td>";
        row += "<td>" + item.status + "</td>";

    if(item.status === "completed"){
        row += "<td><input type='checkbox' name="+ item.id +"/></td>";
    }
    else{
        row += "<td><input type='checkbox' name="+ item.id +"/></td>";
    }

    $("#mylist tbody").append(row);
});

$('#delete').on('click', function() {
    if(confirm("Are you sure to delete selected list?")){
        $('#mylist input:checked').closest('tbody tr').remove();
    }
    else{
        return;
    }

});
```

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/0yhvbur2/1/ I had to add a missing `});` at the end of your code.

Comment: What's the exact problem? You need to be more specific. Unexpected behaviour? A runtime error?

Comment: remove function works in DOM but  I wanted to remove the selected object in my array too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### UPDATE

@Jorge pointed out that it wasn't removing the correct item in array. It's fixed. Changed so that all checkboxes are collected, *then* each one is removed upon the condition of being checked.

Use `.each()` and `.splice()` like this:

```
$('#delete').on('click', function() {
  if(confirm("Are you sure to delete selected list?")){
      $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        if(that.is(':checked')) {
          var obj = that.closest('tr');
          var idx = obj.index();
          obj.remove();
          tasks.splice(idx, 1);
        }...
```

BTW, there's 2 `#myList` but ids **must be unique**, so the div was changed to `#xList`.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>SO41027903</title>

  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>

  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <input id="list-input" />
      <select id="select-status">
        <option value="on-going">on-going</option>
        <option value="completed">completed</option>
      </select>
      <button id="add">Add To List</button>
      <button id="delete">Remove From List</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Your List</h1>

      <div id="xlist">
        <table id="mylist">
          <thead>
            <th>ID Number</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <button id="clear">clear</button>
    </div>


  </section>
  <footer>&nbsp;</footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var tasks = [];
    var count = 0;

    $('document').ready(function() {
      $('#add').click(function() {
        count++;
        var desc = $.trim($('#list-input').val());
        var status = $('#select-status').val();
        var id = Date.now();
        item = {};

        if (!desc) {
          item.id = "";
          alert("Input a description");
          return;
        }

        //clear input field
        $('#list-input').val('');
        $('#list-input').focus();

        item.id = id;
        item.description = desc;
        item.status = status;
        tasks.push(item);


        var row = "<tr>";
        row += "<td id=" + item.id + ">" + item.id + "</td>";
        row += "<td>" + item.description + "</td>";
        row += "<td>" + item.status + "</td>";

        if (item.status === "completed") {
          row += "<td><input type='checkbox' name=" + item.id + "/></td>";
        } else {
          row += "<td><input type='checkbox' name=" + item.id + "/></td>";
        }

        $("#mylist tbody").append(row);
      });

      $('#delete').on('click', function() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure to delete selected list?")) {
          $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            var that = $(this);
            if(that.is(':checked')) {
              var obj = that.closest('tr');
              var idx = obj.index();
              obj.remove();
              tasks.splice(idx, 1);
              count--;
            }

          });
          console.log(tasks);
          
        } else {
          return;
        }

      });


    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```